# What stars are brighter then any star nearer to the south celestial pole

Tags: star, amateur-observing, celestial-mechanics, apparent-magnitude

What stars are brighter (apparent magnitude) then any star nearer to the south celestial pole?
I know that there’s no bright star within a few degrees of the south celestial pole.

Comment: This question is too unspecific. Brighter than what? For our eyes or in absolute terms? At what distance? Just grab a star chart and have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence seems to go:

| Name | Dec | Mag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TYC 9520-363-1 | 89*53' | 11.0 |
| HD99685 | 89*47' | 7.8 |
| HD110994 | 89*46' | 6.8 (V) |
| Sig Oct | 88*57' | 5.45 (V) |
| Chi Oct | 87*36' | 5.25 |
| Del Oct | 83*39' | 4.3 |
| Bet Oct | 81*23' | 4.1 |
| Alf Aps | 79*08' | 3.8 |
| Nu Oct | 77*23' | 3.7 |
| Bet Hyi | 77*16' | 2.8 |
| Bet Car | 69*42' | 1.65 |
| Acrux | 63*05' | 1.25 |
| Alf Cen | 60*48 | 0.1 |
| Canopus | 52*41' | -0.65 |
| Sirius | 16*43' | -1.45 |

Sigma Octans is also known as the southern polaris.

Comment: do you have a source for that table or did you compile it yourself?

Comment: Compiled my self from stellarium, but it would be possible to recreate and check with the yale bright star catalogue